# Stub File.open in Rspec

Tags: ruby, rspec, mocking, stub, rspec3

I know this topic is covered in Stack Overflow, but any of the solutions that they provided didn't work for me. 2 days stuck in the same... starting to be a bit desperate on that.

My original code:

```
url = 'https://someurl/picture.jpg'
file = File.open('new_picture.jpg', 'wb') do |fo|
  fo <<  open(url).read
end
```

I cannot figure it out how to stub this open.
What I tried (in hundred small alternatives and all failed)

```
let(:buffer) {StringIO.new}
let(:picture) {'picture.jpg'}
let(:content) { 'this is just a content to mock up the file' }

before do
  # previous stuff..
  allow(File).to receive(:open).with(picture, 'wb').and_yield(buffer)
end

it 'downloads the image' do
  expect(File).to receive(:open).with(picture,'wb')
  call # this is the way to call the method that contains File.open
end
```

All time receiving errors:

```
expected: ("picture.jpg", "wb")
got: ("/var/folders/55/1mv73gd50779nsdwwh6vkp280000gn/T/open-uri20180315-23631-9dokgj", 2562, {:perm=>384})
```

What am I missing???
As well I tried inside the block `File.open(picture) { |f| f.write(content) }`. it works if I don't invoke `call`. So there I have a green test which never enters in the real method that I want to test.

My main objective: Stub the File.open from the class that invokes this call. then I just want to expect to receive open at any moment... just I want that!

**UPDATED - whole test**

```
require 'pry'
require 'spec_helper'

describe Downloader do
  let(:call) { Downloader.call }
  let(:path) { '/Users/testUser/Downloads/picture.jpg' }

  it 'returns a path' do
    expect(call).to be_a_kind_of(String)
  end

  xcontext 'when the image exists' do
    before { allow_any_instance_of(File).to receive(:exist?).and_return(true) }

    it 'returns the correct path' do
      allow(subject).to receive(:get_existing_file).and_return(path)
      expect(call).to match(/picture/)
      expect(call).to match(/Downloads/)
      expect(call).to match(/Users/)
    end
    it 'does not modify the system' do
      expect(File).not_to receive(:open)
    end
  end
  context 'when the image does not exists' do
    let(:buffer) { StringIO.new }
    let(:picture) { 'picture.jpg' }
    let(:content) { 'this is just a content to mock up the file' }

    before do
      allow(File).to receive(:exist?).and_return(false)
      allow(File).to receive(:open).with(picture, 'wb').and_yield(buffer)
    end

    it 'downloads the image' do
      >>>> GOT STUCK HERE, just removed what I had 
      call

    end
  end
end
```

**SOLUTION**

Finally I decided to go with FakeFs to mock a FileSystem. Here my spec that checks if it exists a file or if it does not.

```
require 'fakefs/spec_helpers'
require 'spec_helper'

describe Downloader do
  include FakeFS::SpecHelpers
  let(:call) { Downloader.call }
  let(:path) { '/Users/testUser/Downloads/example_picture.jpg' }
  let(:buffer) { instance_double(File, path: 'picture.jpg') }

  before do
    config = File.expand_path('~/Downloads', __FILE__)
    FakeFS::FileSystem.clone(config)
    allow(File).to receive(:open).and_return(buffer)
  end
  it 'returns a path' do
    expect(call).to be_a_kind_of(String)
  end

  context 'when the image exists' do
    before { allow_any_instance_of(File).to receive(:exist?).and_return(true) }

    it 'returns the correct path' do
      allow(subject).to receive(:get_existing_file).and_return(path)
      expect(call).to match(/example_picture/)
      expect(call).to match(/Downloads/)
      expect(call).to match(/Users/)
    end
    it 'does not modify the system' do
      expect(File).not_to receive(:open)
    end
  end
  context 'when the image does not exists' do
    before { allow(File).to receive(:exist?).and_return(false) }
    it 'downloads the image' do
      expect(File).to receive(:open)
      call
    end
    it 'puts in the right folder' do
      expect(Dir.pwd).not_to match(/Downloads/)
      call
      expect(Dir.pwd).to match(/Downloads/)
    end
    it 'returns the path with the new image' do
      result = call
      expect(result).to match(/Downloads/)
      expect(result).to match(/picture/)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: So it looks to be like Download.call is the subject of the test. You're setting up doubles like picture, but you're not really testing the class with them.

Download.call doesn't take any arguments? How does the class know what to download? Can you post the Download class.

Comment: buffer, picture and content are just there trying to figure out how to stuvthis call. At the end the only thing that i want to do there is just not to do the regular behaviour for open (it can return whatever, true for example) and then expect call to receive open method, that's it. Download it just downloads a hardcoded url, so i am not expecting right now a param